# Postgresql logical replication between two machine dont't work

Tags: logical-replication, postgresql-15

I have two machines with postgresql v15 and a config like this :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p1Y2XCskOhY&ab_channel=EDB

I have set wal_level to logical but de replication not work, i create a pub in Machine 1 and de sub in the 2 machine with pgAdmin4.

Is there any other setting ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The replication works after re-created subscription.
Is there a solution for synchronization in the other direction automatically (both directions)

Comment: Always remember to add technical infomation in the post like the Postgresql version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).